# Android TextView with HTML & separator

Tags: html, android, textview

I have a TextView that is part of a ListView row item.  In that TextView, i have some HTML rendered using Html.fromHtml().  I'm wondering if there is a way to do what is effectively an `<hr>` tag within the html so that it'll render a horizontal line in between 2 items within the TextView.  is this even possible?

Answer (score 6):

As you can see in the [`Html` class source code](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/Html.java), [`Html.fromHtml(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) does not support all HTML tags. This is a list of allowed HTML tags:

- `br`
- `p`
- `div`
- `em`
- `b`
- `strong`
- `cite`
- `dfn`
- `i`
- `big`
- `small`
- `font`
- `blockquote`
- `tt`
- `monospace`
- `a`
- `u`
- `sup`
- `sub`

So, why don't just use a `WebView` instead of a `TextView`?

Comment: I*'ll try the WebView, but last time i tried it, the performance was a bit laggy whereas the textvie would load up much quicker...

Comment: I dont want to use webView but the text View. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

If you can figure out how to create a visual representation of an hr tag with Span objects then you can use the longer form of the fromHtml method and supply an instance of Html.TagHandler that will replace the hr tag with an Editable that represents that hr.

Comment: "create a visual representation of an hr tag with Span objects" => I cannot find a way to do that. These Spannables are badly documented.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. You can use [Box Drawing Characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) like `═` (this is not the regular equal sign `═`) from Unicode to achieve something similar. However, your line won't fill the whole space.