# android string.xml reading html tags problem

Tags: android, string

In Android project's strings.xml file i have following html text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

<string name="myHeadStr"><b><u>bold, underline </u></b></string>
...

</resources>
```

When i read this into getString(R.string.myHeadStr) it gives only text "bold, underline" it forgets the html tags  and  ....

how to read complete string with html tags from string.xml

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Use XML CDATA

```
<string name="demoStr"><Data><![CDATA[ <b>ABC</b> ]]> </Data></string>
```

getString() will be got `"<b>ABC</b>"`

Comment: No, it is not, this is far too complicated: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18199543/89818

Comment: Mine is stripping it off. I am using the following code: `getResources().getText(R.string.codename)`

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I was receiving an exception on `getResources().getString()` saying my `R.string.mystring` did not exist.  I did a clean and rebuild and `R` would not build.  I removed my `<string>` definition and `R` now builds.  For some reason, the compiler does not like my `<string>` definition.  It is exactly like yours except `<b>ABC</b>` is replaced with my own html.

Comment: @MarcoW.: The OP wants to know how to display the complete string including the tags and not how to format the text, hence the answer is correct.

Comment: Why do you need inner `<Data>` tag? I think using only CDATA is enough

Answer (score 39):

Replace < with &lt;

```
<string name="myHeadStr">&lt;b>&lt;u>bold, underline &lt;/u>&lt;/b></string>
```

Then, when retrieving:

```
Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.myHeadStr));
```

This is the prescribed way of doing in android documentation.
Read the paragraph titled: "Styling with HTML markup" in this link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: When i use it it print data along the tag like not html formatting

Comment: @Sarwar Erfan: it prints the tag but it doesn't actually styling the string, does it?

Answer (score 15):

Directly passing the string resource id to `setText()` or using `Context.getText()` without `Html.fromHtml()` works properly but passing in the the result of `Context.getString()` does not.

ex:

`strings.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <string name="html">This is <b>bold</b> and this is <i>italic</i>.</string>
<resources>
```

code in `Activity.java` file:

```
textView.setText(R.string.html); // this will properly format the text
textView.setText(getText(R.string.html)); // this will properly format the text
textView.setText(getString(R.string.html)); // this will ignore the formatting tags
```

Answer (score 2):

i've run into the same problem by trying to store a complete htmlpage in my rescources.
I finaly solved the problem by changing three things:

1. the "string" node needs to have set the "formatted" attribute to *false*.
2. the stored html page needs to be wrapped in a CData node.
3. the html page is **NOT** alowed to contain apostrophes!

The last one actualy was my main problem.
So here is my strings.xml containing the "properly" stored html page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="error_html" formatted="false" ><![CDATA[<html><head><link name="icon1" href="favicon.ico" rel="SHORTCUT ICON" /><title>Error</title><style>html, body {margin: 0;padding: 0;background: #3f0000;color: white;font-family: Arial;}#MainLink {position: relative;background: #7f0000;margin: 10px;text-decoration: none;border: 1px solid #9f0000;-webkit-border-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius: 10px;border-radius: 10px;-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}#MainLink {width: 462px;height: 220px;}#MainLink td {font-size: 20px;}#MainLink span {text-decoration: underline;font-weight: bold;font-size: 40px;}</style></head><body><table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td align="center" valign="middle"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td colspan="2" id="MainLink" align="center"><big><big><b>Error</b></big></big></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></body></html>]]></string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Good Answer. Just one thing: You can have apostrophes, you just need to escape them with a \ : **\'**


I used them because I needed to store javascript in strings.xml.