# eclipse/android - disable Android localization Files editor

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, localization

I just found out that our CDATA tags and a lot of HTML was removed from the strings.xml Now we are forced to edit it once again. The offender is the Localization Files Editor that's being launched by default when you try to open the strings.xml

I tried to go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Association -> .xml files and remove all other preferences and set XML editor by default. But it turned out if you close/open eclipse it goes and opens the xml file in that same type again.

What should we do? How do we set the default? There is a whole team using this file and every time somebody modifies it we have CDATA removed.

Here is what we did in strings.xm. Similar to the following post (added HTML wrapped in CDATA) [android string.xml reading html tags problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637780/android-string-xml-reading-html-tags-problem) We don't really need any localization and I am not sure why that editor is always being launched despite my defaults?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Check for and uninstall 'Sequoyah Android Localization Editor' and 'Sequoyah Localization Tools' plugins.

Comment: I disable it too because it does not recognize &gt; if I open strings.xml, it changes &gt; to &ampgt; Buggy damn thing, took me one hour to understand why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

I just move all the problematic strings into a separate file (e.g. strings2.xml). That way I can use the localization editor for most strings, and avoid problems with the ones it can't handle.