# Using HREF in Android strings.xml file

Tags: android

I'm trying to assign the below string from the strings.xml file for a TextView android:text property. I'm unable to get the link to show up as a clickable hyperlink.  Any suggestions?  I've tried the below techniques.

```
 <string name="no_device_body">click following link: <![CDATA[<a href="http://cnn.com">link1</a>]]>
 </string>

 <string name="no_device_body">click following link: http://cnn.com">
 </string>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What shows in the textview when you use the second string there? Just the URL but not clickable?

Do you have

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

or

```
android:autoLink="all"
```

set on your TextView in the layout xml file?

Comment: He is not asking how to make a link show up in a TextView but how to embed a link in a string resource.

Comment: Umm really? "I'm unable to get the link to show up as a clickable hyperlink. Any suggestions?" Seems to me like he is having trouble getting it to be clickable in a TextView. autoLink seems relavent to me, just a guess though, I've never tried URLs in the strings xml personally.

Comment: @Tim - this was what was missing.

Comment: I was able to use just the url in the resource file with the text view setting, maybe my question was a bit too vague...

Comment: @c12 what exactly worked for you? which string name format and which autolink?

Answer (score 10):

```
<string name="no_device_body">click following link: &lt;a href="http://findmespot.com/en/index.php?cid=116">link1&lt;/a>"</string>
```

ref: [android string.xml reading html tags problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637780/android-string-xml-reading-html-tags-problem)