# A link inside android string resource doesn't work when doesn't contain domain name

Tags: android, hyperlink

If I put string resource like this:

```
<string name="about_text"><a href="http://example.com/">example.com</a> </string>
```

into TextView like this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_song"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_black"
        android:text="@string/about_text"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:linksClickable="true"/>
```

everything works as expected. But if I put into `<a>` tag something that doesn't fit to schema xxx.yy, any plain word or phrase for example, my link won't work! I've searched through the internet and find no solution. Can somebody explain what is the mistake?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857652/using-href-in-android-strings-xml-file

Comment: I've already seen this answer and it doesn't help me

Comment: actually do you want to display the link in the textview. ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution.

define Html content as string in activity

```
String st=""<html><body><a href=\"http://example.com/\">example.com</a></body></html>"";
```

then set it to textview like this using `Html.fromHtml`

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(st));
```

it will work.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. I want to get working link like <a href="http://example.com/">my random text</a>. But I'm failed to achieve that.

Comment: I've tried your solution. Unfortunately still doesn't work for me

Comment: can you explain what happens?

Comment: The only thing that I can force to work as a link in Android TextView inside <a> ... </a> is text formatted like this: xxx.yy for instance example.com whether I put text into TextView in regular way or as a Html. If I put inside any random text I failed to get it worked as a link. When I use text like "Support Service" it wont work, but if I use "Support service.com" which is nonsense only word "service.com" becomes a link.

Answer (score 0):

You can add :

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

in your `TextView`.