# Bold style not applied for button, textview for some Activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, textview, android-styles

I'm facing an issue with android where the textviews and buttons are not getting the textStyle bold in several activities. I have checked the theme and compared with other activities and all look the same. However The textStyle bold is not working. I have tried using via code and via XML. Is there any way to trace, debug and check why the textStyle bold is not applied on several activities?

I have tried the following

```
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

and also

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/header_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Continue"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Both didn't work for me. Can anyone help why its not working in several activities?

Comment: Did you try refreshing layouts?

Comment: are you using any custom fonts or default fonts?

Comment: just try this  file->invalidate caches /restart it will work

Comment: @D.B. I did refresh the layouts and its still the same. The preview shows as bold but not when running

Comment: @sam I'm using custom fonts. Does this affect for few activities?

Comment: @PranavAshok I'll try that and let you know. Thanks

Comment: See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993904/android-setting-textview-to-bold-not-working/17063538

Comment: yes @Sutha it does. your custom font must have bold type or italic style to support the bold or italic textStyle. that is the problem you are facing.

Comment: @Sam Thanks guys, I found the issue and resolve it. I was using the custom font in a parent class and some activities extended that class. Now resolved the issue by creating different constructors. Thanks

Comment: Good to know, Cheers.. @Sutha

Answer (score 1):

```
android:textStyle="bold"
```

this command always makes the text bold for me. Maybe just try cleaning the project. Because we don't need to build the project to find if command worked. For me, when I enter that command in my xml file, it makes the text bold in preview instantaneously.

Comment: It works in preview, but not when running the application