# how to change string.xml color in paragraph?

Tags: java, android, colors

i want to change a text color in an array in the `value/string.xml` not in the `Layout` but also not all the text but some part of it 
example:

```
<string-array name="list">'

           // like Cafe in example i want it red and bold but not other text.`
             <item>Welcome to Cafe</item>'
            // and shop to be purple
            <item>The new online Shop!</item>'



 //in java i would set 
    welcome.setText(*and one of the array item*);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write html in your string.xml to have them fancy looking.

```
       // like Cafe in example i want it red and bold but not other text.`
         <item>Welcome to <b>Cafe</b></item>'
        // and shop to be purple
        <item>The new online <span style="...">Shop!</span></item>'
        // FOR EXAMPLE ONLY, use XML CDATA in the link provided.

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(YOUR_STRING_FROM_XML), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

See [this post for writing tags in xml.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637780/android-string-xml-reading-html-tags-problem)