# how to display this string is a perfect way in android TextView

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments

<#h> 1

During the morning of the morning of the morning, on the morning of the morning, the sky was filled with the sky full of Calcutta. There is no stoppage of carriage in the street, the ferries have been steadfast, and those who go to court to the court to come to court, have come to the house and have been caught in the kitchen, and the smoke of burning firewood in the kitchen - but so big - the city that is hard heart Calcutta, its hundreds of roads and lanes The trend of gold in the light of today has taken the flow of a wonderful youth today.

when i used Html.format(value) it will print but not this format style how to solve

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static Spanned fromHtml(String html){
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
     return Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
  } else {
     return Html.fromHtml(html);
  }
}
```

Flag parameters:

```
public static final int FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT = 63;
public static final int FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY = 0;
public static final int FROM_HTML_OPTION_USE_CSS_COLORS = 256;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_BLOCKQUOTE = 32;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_DIV = 16;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_HEADING = 2;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_LIST = 8;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_LIST_ITEM = 4;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_PARAGRAPH = 1;
public static final int TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_CONSECUTIVE = 0;
public static final int TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_INDIVIDUAL = 1;
```

You can read more about the different flags on the [Html class documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html#FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)

Answer (score 1):

If you read the String resource from your `strings.xml` you can insert raw HTML into the value by wrapping it like the following:

```
<string name="morning_h1">
    <![CDATA[
        //This is where the html goes
        <h1>During the morning of the morning of the morning, on the morning , etc.</h1>
    ]]>
</string>
```

Set the resource to a `TextView` in your Java code like:

```
Textview morning = findViewById(R.id.morningTextView);
morning.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.morning_h1)));
```

Source which led me to this answer (refers to more sources): [HTML header h1 tags not supported in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393743/html-header-h1-tags-not-supported-in-textview)