# Format text in AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am unable to get text in an AlertDialog to display in bold or italic.

I've tried formatting directly and also using the [CharSequence utilties from the Android string-resource page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) but I  always get just plain text.
What am I doing wrong?

MyFragment.java

```
String idFormatted = String.format(resources.getString(R.string.id));
CharSequence idStyledText = Html.fromHtml(idFormatted);

CharSequence nameItalic = Utilities.italic(resources.getString(R.string.name));

String typeFormatted = String.format(resources.getString(R.string.type));
CharSequence typeStyledText = Html.fromHtml(idFormatted);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setPositiveButton("Dismiss",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        }).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);

builder.setMessage( idFormatted + myData.getId() + "\t\t" +  nameItalic + myData.getName() + "\t\t" +  typeFormatted + myData.getType() );   
Dialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.setTitle("Details");
dialog.show();
```

strings.xml

```
<string name="id"><i>Id: </i></string>
<string name="name"><i>Name: </i></string>
<string name="type"><i>Type: </i></string>
```

Edit: -------------------------------------------------------------
Mohammad Arman suggests that the strings from the string.xml will not retain the html. This seems likely to be true, though I can't prove it yet.

Based on his and Farbod Salamat-Zadeh's answer, I tried the code below, but still the result is the same, just plain text.

```
Spanned idLabel = Html.fromHtml("<i>" + resources.getString(R.string.id) + "</i>");
Spanned nameLabel = Html.fromHtml("<i>" + resources.getString(R.string.name) + "</i>");
Spanned typeLabel = Html.fromHtml("<i>" + resources.getString(R.string.type) + "</i>");
...
builder.setMessage(idLabel.toString() + myData.getId() + "\t\t" + nameLabel + myData.getName());
```

Edit2: -----------------------------------------------------------
I've tried as Keelan has suggested:

```
<string name="italic_string"><![CDATA[<i>italic-string</i>]]></string>
```

and then:

```
String formattedText = getString(R.string.italic_string);
Spanned result = Html.fromHtml(formattedText);
builder.setMessage(result);
```

This works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[You can't simply store HTML in a strings.xml file.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4637780/1544337) You need to put them in CDATA, like so:

```
<string name="id"><![CDATA[<i>Id: </i>]]></string>
```

Then to display a formatted string, you still need to use `Html.fromHtml()`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I just tried your suggestion (see edit to question), but it didn't work. Did I implement it correctly?

Comment: Note the in the link in your answer, the OP doesn't want to format the text, but display the html tags. I want to format the text.

Comment: @AlLelopath the thing is that when you read from strings.xml you don't get the HTML tags. If you use cdata, you *do* get the full tags. What you then do with that string is up to you. *You* would still want to put it in `Html.fromHtml()`. Did you do that? Could you tell me exactly what behaviour you get now? -- **edit**: I see you edited your post, very good (many people don't do that, you're awesome!). So yeah, try with `Html.fromHtml()` and please report back if it works :)

Comment: This works (see edit to question for using `Html.fromHtml()` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can get text anywhere to display in bold or italic - I use the following;

```
Spanned italicText = Html.fromHtml("<i>" + "My italic text" + "</i>");
Spanned boldText = Html.fromHtml("<b>" + "My boldtext" + "</b>");
// You can use different HTML tags depending on what you want.
```

Comment: Those lines don't compile:  Incompatible types: Required: java.lang.String Found: android.text.Spanned

Comment: Try `Spanned italicText` and `Spanned boldText`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to format the html version in a separate `String` variable in Java class (otherwise for some reason it won't work).

```
String myId = <i>Id: </i>;
String myName = <b>Name: </b>
```

Then you have to add this in the textView like bellow:

```
textView1.setText(Html.fromHtml(myId +" "+ "1234");
textView2.setText(Html.fromHtml(myName +" "+ "Al Lelopath")
```

**Why your approach is not working**

It's because as you are importing the string from string.xml it will lose the attribute and send it as a plain text. And that's why Android could not take that as html.

Comment: I tried removing the html from the string xml definition, but still the same. See edit to original question.