# Android string with HTML failed

Tags: android, html, textview

In my strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="informations_links">Read these <b><a href=\"com.android.mobile://ReaderActivity\">general informations</a></b> and <a href=\"com.android.mobile://ReaderActivity\">this main note</a> from this box.</string>
</resources>
```

Then I use it like that:

```
mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.informations_links)));
```

It doesn't work. My text is not formatted.

But if I write directly this and it works (it's the **same** string):

```
mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Read these <b><a href=\"com.android.mobile://ReaderActivity\">general informations</a></b> and <a href=\"com.android.mobile://ReaderActivity\">this main note</a> from this box."));
```

So, what is the best writing in my strings.xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap the string content into `<Data></Data>`

```
<string name="my_string"><Data><![CDATA[<p>This is a paragraph!</p>]]> </Data></string>
```

[android string.xml reading html tags problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637780/android-string-xml-reading-html-tags-problem)