# Syntax highlighting textview displaying source code not putting a new line

Tags: android, textview, syntaxhighlighter

I had to display some source code in my text view along with syntax highlighting
So i used [java prettify jar](https://code.google.com/p/java-prettify/) and imported it into my project and craeted a prettify highlighter class
The highlighting works fine but there is no new line inserted between the code

Like this

[image]

[image]

My code

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="app_name">syntaxtest</string>
<string name="javacode">
    public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);

    }
    }</string>
```

**mainactivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String code = getResources().getString(R.string.javacode);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);

    // code is a String with source code to highlight
     // myTextView is a TextView component
    PrettifyHighlighter highlighter = new PrettifyHighlighter();
    String highlighted = highlighter.highlight("java", code);
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(highlighted));

}
}
```

**prettifyhighlighter class**

```
public class PrettifyHighlighter {
private static final Map<String, String> COLORS = buildColorsMap();

private static final String FONT_PATTERN = "<font color=\"#%s\">%s</font>";

private final Parser parser = new PrettifyParser();

public String highlight(String fileExtension, String sourceCode) {
    StringBuilder highlighted = new StringBuilder();
    List<ParseResult> results = parser.parse(fileExtension, sourceCode);
    for(ParseResult result : results){
        String type = result.getStyleKeys().get(0);
        String content = sourceCode.substring(result.getOffset(), result.getOffset() + result.getLength());
        highlighted.append(String.format(FONT_PATTERN, getColor(type), content));
    }
    return highlighted.toString();
}

private String getColor(String type){
    return COLORS.containsKey(type) ? COLORS.get(type) : COLORS.get("pln");
}

private static Map<String, String> buildColorsMap() {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("typ", "87cefa");
    map.put("kwd", "00ff00");
    map.put("lit", "ffff00");
    map.put("com", "999999");
    map.put("str", "ff4500");
    map.put("pun", "eeeeee");
    map.put("pln", "ffffff");
    return map;
}
  }
```

**tried using the following but nothing worked**

```
 / n <br > <br \> , <![CDATA[ ... ]]>
```

**this is how i tried**

```
    <string name="javacode">
    <![CDATA[

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);<br \>
    setContentView(R.layout.main);<br>
    String code = getResources().getString(R.string.javacode);<br />
    <br />
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);<br />

        ]]>

</string>
```

What shall i do
Help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: html will not recognize `\n` or `\r\n` as new line, you need to somehow use `<br/>`

Comment: @Yazan i tried that also but didnt help

Comment: @Yazan i posted a pic of what happens if i use <br />

Comment: the image link looks broken, it's not appearing

Comment: @Yazan edited the link and reposted the image , plz have a look

Comment: i see the `br` tag is broken, or the > < are not correct! such as `...;br/>...` where is the open tag? or `.../>br/>...` this is invalid right? what about using `&lt;`  and `&gt;` for < > in the strings.xml file

Comment: @Yazan they are getting displayed as such when the app is run, i posted my string as how i did pls have a look

Comment: try use `<data> tag` as in the answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637780/android-string-xml-reading-html-tags-problem

Comment: @Yazan ya will try it now and let you know

Comment: @Yazan tried it , no difference , still the same problem

Comment: @Yazan its working  good without highlighter with this tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(code));, is there something wrong with my highlighter class

Comment: @user5894647: I am not sure but by any chance your `TextView` is single line?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 no its not single line

Comment: @Rohit5k2 have any idea how to incorporate syntax highligh4ing

Comment: @user5894647: Sorry no idea.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 ok tanks bro