# Set onitemclicklistener to search activity search results displayed in a listview

Tags: android, listview, search, parse-platform, onitemclicklistener

My app' s mainactivity consists of a listview that is retrived from parse.com(i know that parse is getting closed and i am also in the process of migrating).onitemclick shows information about the clicked item in singleitemview activity. This works good

I have a search activity that searches user input from list in main activity and display the search results in listview

I want to add onitemclicklistener to the search results so that it would open and show information corresponding to the search ressult clicked in singleitemview activity as it does  in main activity

Now my problem is, I'll try to explain with example

**let my main activity list be**

1. America 1
2. America 2
3. America 3
4. Germany 1
5. Germany 2
6. Germany 3
7. France 1
8. France 2
9. France 3
10. Italy 1

**now the user searches for Germany in edittext of search activity**

The search results displayed are

- Germanny 1
- Germany 2
- Germany 3

**If I click germany 1 item from search results it showing information about America 1 from main activity, ,in singleitemview activity**

**If I click germany 2 item from search results it showing information about America  2 from main activity  in singleitemview activity**
**and so on...**

What shall i do to show correct information for search results

**the search activity code**

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
{

protected  EditText searchedittext;
ImageButton searchButton;
List<ParseObject> ob;
List<CodeList> codelist = null;
FinalAdapter fnladapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_layout);

    searchedittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_layoutEditText);

    final ListView searchedlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.searchlist);
    searchedlist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    searchButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.searchlayoutbtn);

    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                String seaechedit = searchedittext.getText().toString();

                if(seaechedit.isEmpty()){

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage("PLEASE ENTER SOME SEARCH QUERY")
                        .setTitle("EMPTY SEARCH") 
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);

                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();

                }
                else{
                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
                    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
                    // InterActivity7 is the class name in parse database where listview retrives it data from
                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                        "InterActivity");

                    query.whereContains("listheading", seaechedit);
                    query.orderByAscending("_created_at");
                    query.setLimit(200);

                    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

                            @Override
                            public void done(List<ParseObject> p1, ParseException e)
                            {
                                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                                if(e == null){

                                    ob = p1;

                                    String [] searchHeadings = new String[ob.size()];

                                    int i = 0;

                                    // listheading is the coloumn name in parse database
                                    for(ParseObject heading : ob){ searchHeadings[i] = (String) heading.get("listheading");
                                        i++;

                                    }

                                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( SearchActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, searchHeadings );
                                    searchedlist.setAdapter(adapter);


                                }else{

                                    Log.e("searchactivity", e.getMessage()); 
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchActivity.this); 
                                    builder.setMessage(e.getMessage()) 
                                        .setTitle("Nothing found")
                                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null); 
                                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                    dialog.show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                }


            }

        });

}

private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();



    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array
        codelist = new ArrayList<CodeList>();
        try {
            // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "InterActivity");
            // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending
            query.orderByAscending("_created_at");

            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject inter : ob) {


                map.setIntroduction((String) inter.get("intro"));


                codelist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


        fnladapter = new FinalAdapter(SearchActivity.this,
                                      codelist);

    }

}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p1, View p2, int position, long p4)
{


        Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, SingleItemView.class);


        intent.putExtra("intro",
                        (codelist.get(position).getIntroduction()));



        // Start SingleItemView Class
        //   startActivity(intent);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);



    }
 }
```

**Codelist**

```
public class CodeList
{
private String listHeading;

private String introduction;

   public void setListHeading(String listHeading)
{
    this.listHeading = listHeading;
}

public String getListHeading()
{
    return listHeading;
}



public void setIntroduction(String introduction)
{
    this.introduction = introduction;
}

public String getIntroduction()
{
    return introduction;
}
```

}

**getview() of fnlwdapter**

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if(view == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beg_list_item,null);
        holder.listHeading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.beg_list_itemTextView);



        holder.favariteImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.favbtn);

        view.setTag(holder);

    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    CodeList codes = (CodeList) getItem(position);
    holder.listHeading.setText(codeList.get(position).getListHeading());




    if (checkFavoriteItem(codes)) {
        holder.favariteImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite);
        holder.favariteImage.setTag("yes");
    } else {
        holder.favariteImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.unfavorite);
        holder.favariteImage.setTag("no");
    }                    





    return view;
}
```

Comment: try yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after your search..

Comment: @sunilsunny i dindt understand could be be more specific

Comment: Ok you are using an array adapter right ?

((ArrayAdapter)list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); call this method after your new results are obtained.

Comment: @sunilsunny ho2 will that help

Comment: @user5894647 Just fetch the data from filtered list. You are using original list. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting position of item from filtered list (list after search), but you are fetching item from the unfiltered list. This is causing the new activity to show wrong data. Get the item from currently loaded list.

Replace

```
intent.putExtra("intro",
                    (codelist.get(position).getIntroduction()));
```

with

```
String value = (String)p1.getItemAtPosition(position);
for(int i = 0; i < codelist.size(); i++)
{
    CodeList itemData = (CodeList)codelist.get(i);
    String temp = itemData.getListHeading();
    if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(temp))
    {
        intent.putExtra("intro", itemData.getIntroduction());
        intent.putExtra("conclusion", itemData.getconclusion());
        break;
    }

    if(i == codelist.size() - 1)
    {
        Log.e("onItemClick", "No item found to display");
        retrun;
    }
}
```

in `onItemClick`

Comment: I will try iit and let you know,thnx

Comment: @user5894647: Update my answer. Didn't notice item was a string.

Comment: bro its showing heading of the listitem clicked instead of showing introduction as it would show if it is clicked from mainactivity

Comment: Do you have this heading in `codelist` items? If yes then search this item in `codelist` using a loop and fetch the introduction.

Comment: Is `CodeList` your class? Can you post it?

Comment: ya its my class. I ll post it

Comment: Also post `getView` method of `FinalAdapter`

Comment: Sorry, missed something. Try now.

Comment: ya doing it , thnx for your concern

Comment: ya that worked,in case i have to add conclusion also do i have to do the same procedure you told for introduction

Comment: like if i had to add conclusion along with introduction ,, like this     intent.putExtra("conclusion
                    (codelist.get(position).getconclusion()));

Comment: Updated my answer to add conclusion.

Comment: and also i have to add intent.putextra("conclusion" , value);

Comment: No I removed that from my answer. Just the code block I have provided.

Comment: ya ya ok thank you very much, you were the best and most patient coder i have ever met on stack overflow. You waited till my problem was solved

Comment: I am sure there are many others like me. But thanks for your compliment :D

Comment: A very big hug and by the way saw your website, really good, thank you

Comment: bro i had another unsolved problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/35535105/5894647,,  I think you can solve it easily. Would you please like to help

Comment: @user5894647: Saw your question but sorry to say I have never worked on that library.

Comment: bro this is my new problem will please help and be my saviour http://stackoverflow.com/q/35670410/5894647

Answer (score 0):

try setting custom adapter to `searchedlist`. as of now you are setting `ArrayAdapter<String>` instead of that try settings adapter of `ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<CodeList>>`

and then in `onItemClick` you will get `CodeList` object; then you can use this object to pass to next activity via `intent`

Comment: I will try your method also bro and let you know thank you very much