# Same file with same name getting downloaded even when provided with different URLs

Tags: android, download, outputstream

I have a activity that contains a listview and sends different url when different list item is clicked via intent in onitemclicklistener
 In the singleitemview activity which is opened when list item is clicked  i have a button to download images

The problem is only 1 image is getting downloaded even different URLs are provided through different list item clicks

I think this is happening because of providing only 1 outputstream like this

```
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/download/loadedfile.png");
```

how to change this so each different image gets downloaded with its own file name

**onitemclicklistener of listview**

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p1, View view, int position, long p4)
{

       Intent intent = new Intent(ProActivity.this, SingleItemView.class);
      intent.putExtra("download",
                        (codelist.get(position).getDownloadCode()));
              staetActivity(intent);
      }
```

**My download class**

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{



    /**
     * Before starting background thread
     * Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;

        try{


            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);

            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            // Output stream
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/download/loadedfile.png");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();

            Log.e("Error: ","Error Message ::" +  e.getMessage());


        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task
     * Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String downurl) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded


        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

        Toast.makeText(SingleItemView.this,
                       getString(R.string.download_complete),
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

}
```

1

**onclick method for my download button in singlitemview activity**

```
Intent i = getIntent();
file_url = i.getStringExtra("download");
public void downloadnow(){

  // different url is recived from different list item click via intent
    String downurl = file_url;

    new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(downurl);
}
```

Comment: set name using System.currentTimeMillis().

Comment: @KeyurLakhani but i want to give it a name i desire for different files

Comment: @KeyurLakhani bro could you be more specific

Comment: What does your url look like? Can you post one sample? Does it have the file name of the file to be downloaded?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 the url is something like http:// thehostingsite where the file is located .the extension of the file(like .png or .jpeg)

Comment: @user5894647 have you tried my answer? It stores the `http://thehostingsite/123.png` to `/sdcard/download/123.png`

Comment: @VasilyKabunov bro 7 was out for some work, . I ll try it and let you know,. Thnx very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change file name `loadedfile.png` to downloaded file name.

Something like:

```
String fileName = url.substring( url.lastIndexOf('/')+1, url.length() );
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/download/" + filename);
```

Comment: Bro that worked but only url passed from 1st list item bets downl8aded and the urls from rest of the list items do not download,,the progress bar just appewars and dissapears and even the toast appears but the download is not done