# Android string colors

Tags: android, string, colors

Is it possible to change the color of some of the characters in a string in Android? For example change the color of the letters d and r in the word android to green.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/word"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="30pt"/>
```

Comment: I'm just using the XML TextView such the one I inserted above in the main question. I display the text in the main code using word.setText("Android") but I need to change some of the characters to different colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could initialize the TextView with html instead of plain text. The html could define the text spans with colors. See [Set TextView text from html-formatted string resource in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235131/set-textview-text-from-html-formatted-string-resource-in-xml) for how.

In case you don't want to use html you can use [SpannableString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android).