# How to make Resources.getStringArray work with HTML markup in Android

Tags: android, arrays

I have an XML file in `res/values` with a string array, whose items contains simple HTML markup, such as:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="frases31">
        <item>They <u>were not</u> before.</item>
        <item>I don\'t think <u>he</u> is.</item>
...
```

I load these into a `String[]` array this way:

```
Resources res = mContext.getResources();
exercise.setSentences(res.getStringArray(R.array.frases31));
```

The trouble is the `String[]` array in variable `exercise`, which is called `sentences` contains only the strings, the HTML markup (`<u>` and `</u>`) has disappeared.
Should I store the result of calling `res.getStringArray(R.array.frases31)` in a special variable?
I have an index and I will put `sentences[i]` in a `TextView` programmatically.

Comment: Since `getStringArray()` returns `String[]`, and not `CharSequence[]`, I suspect that markup is not allowed. You could try wrapping your strings in `CDATA`, so the tags are left alone, then parse the resulting strings with `Html.fromHtml()`.

Comment: It has to work, according to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray. The `item` sub-element in a `string-array` element is "A string, which can include styling tags". The answer works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to edit the XML to achieve this. You can wrap your items with CDATA to preserve the markup:

```
<item><![CDATA[They <u>were not</u> before.]]></item>
<item><![CDATA[I don\'t think <u>he</u> is.]]></item>
```

Or escape each markup character individually:

```
<item>They &lt;u&gt;were not&lt;/u&gt; before.</item>
<item>I don\'t think &lt;u&gt;he&lt;/u&gt; is.</item>
```

Comment: Escaping each markup character worked and I had to use `Html.fromHtml()` passing the string with the markup characters escaped. The documentation at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray is a bit confusing, seems as though escaping and calling `Html.fromHtml()` is only necessary when you create a "styled text resource that is also used as a format string", in fact it is necessary as well when creating just a styled text resource.