# HTML Formatting in TextView

Tags: android, html, textview

All,

I have the following in my string resource xml file.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <resources>
>
> <string name="hello">Hello World, ProDroid_Android!</string>
> <string name="app_name">ProDroid_Android-CH3-Resources</string>
>
> <plurals name ="eggs_in_A_basket">
>     <item quantity ="one"> There is 1 egg</item>
>     <item quantity = "other"> There are %d eggs</item>
>
> </plurals>
> <string name="simple_string">simple string</string>
> <string name="quoted_string">"Quoted String 'xyz' string"</string>
> <string name="double_quoted_string">\"Double Quoted String\""\";</string>
> <string name="java_format_string">Hello %2$s Java format String. %1$s again.</string>
>
> <string name="tagged_string">Hello <b><i> Slanted Android.</i></b>, You are bold</string>
> ```

When I go to put the tagged_string into a TextView with the HTML formatting it does not display with it's formatting. However, if I cut and paste the **Hello  ***Slanted Android.***, You are bold** and manually put it into .setText it works, or if I set it statically in my layout xml file. However using the Java code below it does not work (All you see is unformatted text):

```
//HTML
        TextView t6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);

        t6.setText(Html.fromHtml(ProDroid_Android.this.getString(R.string.tagged_string)));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you format your text in XML it isn't necessary to use `Html.formatHtml(...)`

Try this:

```
t6.setText(getString(R.string.tagged_string);
```

**EDIT**:
Hmm... This way worked for me fine and I tried **exactly** your String. 
Maybe your Project needs a clean (Project > Clean ...)

If this doesn't help:
I found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235131/set-textview-text-from-html-formatted-string-resource-in-xml). Maybe the answer there can solve your problem

Comment: No this did not do it. Any other thoughts? I am running API 10.