# Android: formatting portion of text doesn't work

Tags: android, textview, android-textattributes

In my strings.xml file I have defined the following:

```
<string name="mystring"><b>Bold text</b>Non-bold text</string>
```

It should work, as it's specified [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext). But actually only bold text is displayed, and the other part of text is gone.

Comment: Is your TextView using a Spannable storage?

Comment: No. There's no need in Spannable for simple text formatting according to android documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235131/set-textview-text-from-html-formatted-string-resource-in-xml) SO thread

use this

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(someText));
```

or from xml by this way

You CAN include raw HTML in strings.xml, as long as you wrap it in

```
<![CDATA[ ...raw html... ]]>
```

Example:

```
<string name="nice_html">
<![CDATA[
<p>This is a html-formatted string with <b>bold</b> and <i>italic</i> text</p>
<p>This is another paragraph of the same string.</p>
]]>
</string>
```

Then, in your code:

```
TextView foo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.foo);
foo.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.nice_html)));
```

you can also backslash-escape apostrophes/single-quotes inside the CDATA block, so you can have things like `<b>can\'t</b>` instead of the infinitely-uglier `<b>can&apos;t</b>`

Comment: But what if I need to use strings.xml for different localisations?

Comment: Thanks, it works. And the last question - can I somehow set html text in layout.xml file, or only in code?

Comment: i think you can't if you set your html text in your android:text attribute you will get your html tag printed too, the trick is to use the class Html and then use the method from Html and all that with code!!