# How to implement a SpannableStringBuilder where only a certain part is colored?

Tags: android, emoji, spannablestringbuilder

I need to implement a string that changes the color of some parts of it to highlight it. I need to create something like a hotkey guide that displays the action you could perform by pressing the highlighted number. I used to use Html. from HTML but I've read that it's not fast because of the parsing. I need to run the code on a slow device. This is my current code.

```
private SpannableStringBuilder spannedTxt(String txt, int count){
        String tagStart = "<p>", tagEnd = "</p>";
        String temp = txt;
        int emojCount = count /2;
        emojCount += 1;

        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(temp);
            Log.d(TAG, "convertToSpan: "+spannable.toString());

            spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),
                    txt.indexOf(tagStart) + tagStart.length(), txt.indexOf(tagEnd),
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            ssb.append(spannable);

            temp = temp.replaceFirst(tagStart, "");
            temp = temp.replaceFirst(tagEnd, "");
        }

        return ssb;
    }
```

What it currently does is change the style of the first substring inside `<p>` and `</p>` which is a number. For some reason, the tagStart and tagEnd aren't removed from the final SpannableStringBuilder even though when I logged it shows that the tags are removed. 
I used `<p>` and `</p>` to know which part is the once that need to be colored. I needed that because the action could also contain numbers and I don't need to recolor those numbers on the action. For example, Action 1 (Press 1). The string also contains emojis between each action and I use the count of those to know how many actions do the string contain.

**Simpler explanation:**
What I need to make is below

Action 1 (Press `<p>`1`</p>`)   Action 2 (Press `<p>`2`</p>`) to

```html
Action 1 (Press <font color="red">1</font>)&nbsp;&nbsp; Action 2 (Press <font color="red">2</font>)
```

Something like that using SpannableStringBuilder

Comment: Can you put an expected example.What u want as an example.

Comment: Do you mean my expected output?

Comment: Actually I'm unable to understand your question at all. Please elaborate once.

Comment: I've added a shorter explanation

Comment: So you want to change the color of text in-closed with <p></p>, using spannable ?

Comment: yes. and after changing the color of the number, I want to also remove the <p> and </p>. At first, I wanted to change the color of the hotkey number without using a loop but I think I can't do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some thinking, I found a solution for my problem. I changed a bit of how I create my string for the SpannableStringBuilder.

```
Action 1 (Press <p>[1]<p>)    �� ��    Action 2 (Press <p>[2]<p>)    �� ��    Action 3 (Press <p>[3]<p>)
```

Using the string above, I've modified my code to the code below.

```
private SpannableStringBuilder spannedTxt(String txt){
        String tagStart = "<p>";
        String temp = txt;

        String[] actTxtArr = txt.split(tagStart);

        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < actTxtArr.length; i++) {
            String arrTxt = actTxtArr[i];
            SpannableString spannable;

            if(arrTxt.contains("[")){
                arrTxt = arrTxt.replace("[", "");
                arrTxt = arrTxt.replace("]", "");

                spannable = new SpannableString(arrTxt);

                spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),
                        arrTxt.indexOf(arrTxt), arrTxt.indexOf(arrTxt) + arrTxt.length(),
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }else{
                spannable = new SpannableString(arrTxt);
            }

            ssb.append(spannable);
        }

        return ssb;
    }
```

Now it works the way I wanted it to be. I hope someone who might need to implement something like the one that I did find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Html.fromHtml() static function to parse HTML code to a TextView text with properties (as the HTML's ones), as shown below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11062756/5417056

Comment: As I've said on my question, I would like to use SpannableStringBuilder because Html.fromHtml is quite slow because of the parsing needed for it to work from a SO answer I've read before and I need to run it on a slow device.