# Using HTML in Android Alert Dialog

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-alertdialog

I have some amount of informations to be displayed in Dialog Box. It comes like Title, then under it text; Title, then under it text. Like wise, there are 4 titles and 4 descriptions to be displayed. It should come like this

### **Title One**

description;description;description;description;description;description;description;description;description;description;description;description;description;description;description

### **Title Two**

description;description;description;description;description;description;description;description;description;description;description;description;description;description;description

As you can see, there are bold texts, underlined texts, line breaks etc. I want to add this kind of a text to the alert box, so below is what I tried.

```
TextView msg = new TextView(this);
msg.setText("<html><u>Message</u></html>")

AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
ab.setTitle("Title");
ab.setView(msg);
ab.setCancelable(false);

//rest of the code
```

However this trick didn't work. What happened is, all the HTML tags showed up as they are! And the text is not clear! Seems like it mixed with the background of the default colour of AlertBox, black. How can I solve this issue? Please help!

PS: Or am I using the wrong method? Wrong dialog box?

Comment: For this you don't need to create a new view `msg`. You can simply use `ab.setText(Html.fromHtml( ... ))`. Also note that the `ab` methods can be chained.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You will need to use [`Html.fromHtml()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) to use HTML tags in `TextView` as:

```
msg.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>Message</u>"))
```

And you also see all [HTML tags supported by `TextView`](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html).

Comment: Also, remember if you pull the message from `strings.xml` (a good idea in the longer term), you must [escape the HTML using CDATA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425002/android-html-in-strings-xml) or you won't see any formatting.

Comment: Works like wonder!! Thanks.@ρяσѕρєя K please, do you think you could help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598696/recommended-way-order-to-read-data-from-a-webservice-parse-that-data-and-inse

Comment: If you get a deprecation warning when using Html.fromHtml, look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37905107/183791)

Answer (score 18):

As it turns out, you don't actually need any extra TextViews to do this.  Simply include the HTML in your alert's "setMessage()" call (which replaces the "setView()" call in your question) and pass it the html-formatted string.  Be sure to only use `<b>`, `<u>`, and `<i>` in your formatting, though because those are the only tags it supports.  If you're using a String resource for the text in your alert, call `getResources().getText(R.id.yourHtmlString)` rather than `getResources().getString(R.id.yourHtmlString)`, though, or the tags will be completely stripped from the String.

Comment: Oh my god. I am developing Android apps for like 6 years now and I didn't know about Resources#getText. I was using Resources#getString all my life. This helps so much. THANKS! +1

Answer (score 9):

If you want to add a link and make it clickable,

```
msg.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
msg.setClickable(true);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need to add more complex `HTML`, with `CSS` and `META`, you can add a `WebView` to the dialog, like this:

```
String webViewString = yourMeta + yourCss + yourHtml;
yourCustomWebView.loadData(webViewString, "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
                    null);
yourAlertDialog.setView(yourCustomWebView);
```

This way, you can display fully formatted HTML pages in your dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,
Font color,

```
   String source = "<b><font color=#ff0000> Loading. Please wait..."
                + "</font></b>";
```

Font underline,

```
   String source = <u>Message</u>

 msg.setText(Html.fromHtml(source));
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if you need it.
Better to use `HtmlCompat.fromHtml((htmlString, 0)` for compatibility with older versions.