# how to display special chars in a android button/textview?

Tags: android

I need to display s.th. like `10ˣ` on a android button or textview.

So I added it to the `strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="a10x">10ˣ</string>
</resources>
```

the problem is, then I start the app I just see the 10 and the x is missing.

How to fix this?

Comment: use escape character \ before your special character.

Comment: Think you will have to find the unicode value for the power of x and insert that there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<string name="10x">10ˣ</string>
```

Please change this variable name to something like start with alphabets. Because this will produce error in `R.java` file. `public static final int 10*=0x7f04009a;` see here, Your variable will create a variable in `R.java` like this. This is wrong in java naming conversion. I hope this is only problem.  Otherwise use some codes like `&#160`, this is for single space.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: this was just for the example, it starts with an a

Comment: Oh.. Okay.. Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android).

Comment: And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425002/android-html-in-strings-xml) one for load from string.xml

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("10<sup>x</sup>"));
```