# how to write subscript and superscript in the textview text?

Tags: android, string-formatting, textview

I'm working on app on android studio and i need subscript and superscript in my       `textview` and I know how to do it programmatic-ally like:

---

```
  Html.fromHtml(r7.getText().toString()+"  m<sup><small>2</small></sup>")
```

---

but when writing it the text of `textview` give me this error:

---

> Error:(104) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

---

**So how to solve this problem, please ???**

Comment: see following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425002/android-html-in-strings-xml

Answer (score 7):

please check my answer in this [line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android/42112522#42112522)
Simply use `SpannableString` that will solve your problem.

```
 SpannableString styledString = new SpannableString("9-10th STD");
 styledString.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), 4, 6, 0);
 textView.setText(styledString);
```

and put your `android:textAllCaps="false"`

Answer (score 2):

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling the only supported HTML markup is `<u>`, `<i>`, and `<b>`. To get sub- and superscripts, you'll probably need to use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/SubscriptSpan.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/SuperscriptSpan.html .

Comment: information a bit outdated. Please read carefully https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#FormattingAndStyling