# Android Text and Scrolling Views – Why isn't HTML-formatted text rendering as such?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, textview

I'm following Google's [Android fundamentals V2 course](https://developer.android.com/courses/fundamentals-training/overview-v2) and working through [1.3 text and scrolling views](https://developer.android.com/courses/fundamentals-training/toc-v2).

The assignment simply asks you to use a RelativeLayout to arrange some TextViews and display sample content.

I've followed the directions precisely, but I'm not getting the same result that the tutorial is (left screenshot is the tutorial's; the right one is mine—don't mind the color differences):

[image]

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.example.android.scrollingtext.MainActivity">

   <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/article_heading"
      android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
      android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular"
      android:text="@string/article_title"
      android:textAppearance=
                  "@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:textStyle="bold" />

   <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/article_subheading"
      android:layout_below="@id/article_heading"
      android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular"
      android:text="@string/article_subtitle"
      android:textAppearance=
                  "@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault" />

   <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/article"
      android:layout_below="@id/article_subheading"
      android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/line_spacing"
      android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular"
      android:text="@string/article_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**strings.xml**:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Scrolling Text</string>
    <string name="article_title">Beatles Anthology Vol. 1</string>
    <string name="article_subtitle">Behind That Locked Door: Beatles Rarities!</string>
    <string name="article_text">In a vault deep inside Abbey Road Studios in London — protected by
        an unmarked, triple-locked, police-alarmed door — are something like 400 hours of unreleased
        Beatles recordings, starting from June 2, 1962 and ending with the very last tracks recorded
        for the <i>Let It Be</i> album. The best of the best were released by Apple Records in the
        form of the 3-volume Anthology series. For more information, see the Beatles Time Capsule at
        www.rockument.com.
\n\n
This volume starts with the first new Beatle song, “Free as a Bird” (based on a John Lennon demo,
        found only on <i>The Lost Lennon Tapes Vol. 28</i>, and covers the very earliest historical
        recordings, outtakes from the first albums, and live recordings from early concerts and BBC
        Radio sessions.
\n\n
<b>Highlights include:</b>
\n\n
<b><i>Cry for a Shadow</i></b> - Many a Beatle fanatic started down the outtake road, like I did,
        with a first listen to this song. Originally titled “Beatle Bop” and recorded in a single
        session that yielded four songs (the other three featured Tony Sheridan with the Beatles as
        a backing band), “Cry for a Shadow” is an instrumental written by Lennon and Harrison, which
        makes it unique to this day. John Lennon plays rhythm guitar, George Harrison plays lead
        guitar, Paul McCartney plays bass, and Pete Best plays drums. The sessions were produced by
        Bert Kaempfert in Hamburg, Germany, during the Beatles’ second visit from April through July
        of 1961 to play in the Reeperbahn-section clubs.
\n\n
<b><i>My Bonnie</i></b> and <b><i>Ain’t She Sweet</i></b> — At the same session, the Beatles played
        on “My Bonnie” (the first-ever single with Beatles playing), as the backing band for English
        singer Tony Sheridan, originally a member of the Jets. The popularity of this single in
        Liverpool brought the Beatles to the attention of Brian Epstein, who worked in the NEMS record
        store and tried to meet demand for the disc. John Lennon then sings a fine “Ain’t She Sweet”
        (his first-ever released vocal).
\n\n
<b><i>Searchin</i></b> — A Jerry Leiber - Mike Stoller comedy song that was a hit for the Coasters
        in 1957, and a popular live favorite of the Beatles. The Coasters also had a hit with “Besame
        Mucho” and the Beatles covered that song as well. Ringo Starr had by now replaced Pete Best
        on drums. The high falsetto is George, who also plays a hesitant lead guitar. This is from
        their first audition for Decca Records in London on Jan 1., 1962, live in the studio. The
        Grateful Dead would later cover “Searchin” with a similar arrangement, Pigpen doing the Paul
        vocals. A live version is available on outtake records featuring the Dead joined by the Beach
        Boys!
\n\n
<b><i>Love Me Do</i></b> — An early version of the song, played a bit slower and with more of a blues
        feeling, and a cool bossa-nova beat in middle. Paul had to sing while John played harmonica
        — a first for the group. Pete Best played drums on this version.
\n\n
<b><i>She Loves You – Till There Was You – Twist and Shout</i></b> — Live at the Princess Wales Theatre
        by Leicester Square in London, attended by the Queen. “Till There Was You” (by Meredith Wilson)
        is from the musical The Music Man and a hit for Peggy Lee in 1961. Before playing it, Paul
        said it was recorded by his favorite American group, “Sophie Tucker” (which got some laughs).
        At the end, John tells the people in the cheaper seats to clap their hands, and the rest to
        “rattle your jewelry” and then announces “Twist and Shout” (a song by Bert Russell and Phil
        Medley that was first recorded in 1962 by the Isley Brothers). A film of the performance shows
        the Queen smiling at John’s remark.
\n\n
<b><i>Leave My Kitten Alone</i></b> — One of the lost Beatle songs recorded during the “Beatles For
        Sale” sessions but never released. This song, written by Little Willie John, Titus Turner, and
        James McDougal, was a 1959 R&amp;B hit for Little Willie John and covered by Johnny Preston
        before the Beatles tried it and shelved it. A reference to a “big fat bulldog” may have influenced
        John’s “Hey Bulldog” (Yellow Submarine album), which is a similar rocker.
\n\n
<b><i>One After 909</i></b> — A song recorded for the <i>Let It Be</i> album was actually worked on
        way back in the beginning, six years earlier. This take shows how they did it much more slowly,
        with an R&amp;B feel to it.
</string>
</resources>
```

**Question**: Why isn't the formatting rendering on my end? Here's all the info for my Android Studio installation (I know it's not the latest version—could that have something to do with what's going on?):

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/13425002/6296561

Comment: So Google's own tutorial is broken? That seems odd.

Answer (score -1):

i resolved your problem and edited :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_heading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular"
        android:text="@string/article_title"
        android:textAppearance=
          "@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_subheading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular"
        android:text="@string/article_subtitle"
        android:textAppearance=
          "@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault"/>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/line_spacing"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular"
        android:text="@string/article_text"/>

    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Please indicate the solution in text instead of just code. How can we see what should resolve the issue by looking at this swath of XML?