# How to make string-array texts as HTML formatted texts

Tags: android, html

I want to format texts so that they can appear real in their form. The text I'm making has different characters in italics, bold and plain. Please help me. I was trying to place the html texts but it gave error HTML TEXTS

```html
<string-array name="newbrandDesc">
        <item>Lyrics Here in bold and in italis with text margins and spaces for No.1</item>
        <item>Lyrics Here in bold and in italis with text margins and spaces for No.2</item>
        <item>Lyrics Here in bold and in italis with text margins and spaces for No.3</item>
        <item>Lyrics Here in bold and in italis with text margins and spaces for No.4</item>
        <item>Lyrics Here in bold and in italis with text margins and spaces for No.5</item>
    </string-array>
```

Comment: @harjinder bains, how can i use <item> text here</item> to pass array-list into listview. Is there a way a i can use CDATA and pass into <item>????

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML tags for underline, italic, bold and so on. You can follow this link [Android: html in strings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425002/android-html-in-strings-xml)  I hope it would helpful.