# How do I do multiline with TextView

Tags: android, textview, multiline

I have an `Activity` called `MainActivity.java`, with an `activity_main.xml` file. But I don't know how to create multi line textviews when I try to add the second line it puts both lines on the same line at the same space.

activity_main.xml textview

```
<TextView  android:id="@+id/txtView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="" 
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColorLink="#FFFF00"
    android:textStyle="bold"
/
<TextView  android:id="@+id/txtView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="" 
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.alatecinc.eema.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

    //Main Menu Links
    String str = "Directions";
    SpannableString content = new SpannableString(str);
    content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, str.length(), 0);
    final TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
    txtView.setText(content);
    txtView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    Linkify.addLinks(txtView, Linkify.ALL);     
    txtView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainMenuActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, DirectionActivity.class));
        }
    });

    String mapStr = "Map View";
    SpannableString mapContent = new SpannableString(mapStr);
    mapContent.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, mapStr.length(), 0);
    final TextView mapTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView1);
    mapTxtView.setText(mapContent);
    mapTxtView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    Linkify.addLinks(mapTxtView, Linkify.ALL);      
    mapTxtView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainMenuActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, DirectionActivity.class));
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
              getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
          return true;
     }

 }
```

So what I need is to have two lines one that says Directions and one that says mapview.

Comment: Why don't you just make two different `TextView`'s in your manifest xml?

Comment: Just give the width of the `TextView` as `wrap_content` and then try.

Comment: Wait just saw that you do. My bad. Didn't fully read the xml. HOwever are you using a `RelativeLayout`, or what? Try using a `RelativeLayout` and then placing them above/below each other?

Comment: Post full xml. Also, may be a copy/paste error but you are missing ">" in your first `TextView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".yourActivity" >
<TextView  android:id="@+id/txtView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="" 
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColorLink="#FFFF00"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<TextView  android:id="@+id/txtView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtView"
    android:text="" 
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Some of the information in the `<RelativeLayout>` tag may be specific to your app. Just make sure you watch that.

Comment: how so?  Or could you go a little more in Depth?

Comment: By the way I really appreciate the answer it was quick and to the point.

Comment: Glad I could help. Didn't notice your other comment til now, the `tools:context` and maybe the `xmnls` tags would have needed modifing for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Use a relative layout and set the txtView2 to be below txtView1 explicitly.
I wouldn't not go for the HTML solution as it defeats the purpose of having seperate layout files.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/txtView1"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/txtView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" 
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:layout_below="@id/txtView1"/>
```

Comment: Sorry Niel I saw TronicZomb's response before this but I do really appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<div>line1</div> <br /> <div>line2</div>"));
```

Comment: HTML code in TextView to do multilines... LOL ! Do you kill a fly with a cannon ?

Comment: This is a way of to do it ! If you have a better idea just write your answer ! This not a place which you can make fun with answers !

Comment: StephaneT I agree with talhakosen.  Try to be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `\n` when you want add new line. like

```
String str = "Title:\nHere title";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your text in strings.xml file.Yes,you can define formatted html in it too.

So you can try this out:

```
<string name="nice_html">
<![CDATA[Don&apos;t worry we will never share this with anyone<br/>
By Clicking register you are indicating that you have read and agreed to the <br/>
 <u>Terms of services</u>  and <u>Privacy Policy</u>
]]></string>
```

Then, in your code:

```
TextView foo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.foo); foo.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.nice_html)));
```

[Original answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235131/set-textview-text-from-html-formatted-string-resource-in-xml/3237438#3237438)

This is the cleanest way to do it.Inshallah.

Answer (score 0):

you can add android:maxLines="5" attribute in textview in your xml file.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

That's it

Comment: Uhhh this was answered two years ago.