# Android TextView in BOLD and Normal text

Tags: android, android-layout

I thoroughly searched on SO but didnt get answer of my question.

I want to set a paragraph, I will set it in XML using

The text contains Title and Steps and regular text. I want to make the Title and Steps in bold and rest in normal text.

I can do this by using different  's but how can I do it in the same TextView.

I mean using the same TextView how can I set different attributes for different sentences?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6159538/1051147

Answer (score 15, accepted):

in your strings file

```
<string name="your_text">
<![CDATA[
<p> <b>Title</b> </p>
<p><b><i>Step 1</i></b><p>step1 content content content  content content content</p></p>
<p><b><i>Step 2</i></b><p>step2 content  content content content  content content content</p></p>
]]>
</string>
```

Then in your activity

```
        TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.your_text)));
```

And output

[image]

Comment: In this case we directly use the values in String , so XML involved na?

Comment: Tried this but its not considering spaces : 

<p>   43<br /> x 78<br />____<br />   4</p>

Even in comments its not taking spaces...there are 3 spaces before 43 and 4

Comment: should I use &nbsp  ? It will work but any other alternative?

Answer (score 31):

Use a Spannable String

```
 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);  
 String steps = "Hello Everyone";
 String title="Bold Please!";

 SpannableString ss1=  new SpannableString(title);
 ss1.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, ss1.length(), 0); 
 tv.append(ss1);
 tv.append("\n");
 tv.append(steps);
```

[image]

For more styling check the link @ http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/177

Comment: [Here is the Screenshot](http://image.prntscr.com/image/bbe1b95ceedf437eae54a751986c8641.png)    Thanks, this works fine for me! As you can see I could set BOLD for "Title", "Author" and "Tags".

Answer (score 3):

You can format it like you would in HTML: let's call this `custom_text`

```
<b>Your title here</b>
This is the non-bolded stuff.
```

And then load the text using the `Html` class:

```
mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.custom_text)));
```

That will create a spannable string and set it on the TextView.

Comment: any other way without using HTML bro?

Comment: Can we do it directly in XML <TextView> instead of String.xml ?

Answer (score 3):

please put this string in to **res->string.xml**

```
<string name="your_html">
    <![CDATA[p><b>This is bold text</b> rementing is simple text

    ]]>
    </string>
```

Now you can used whenever you have to require this thing.

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.your_html)));
```

It is bestway and work charm.

Comment: Hi I tried all the way making string Bold and Italic in Android M, its not working.

Answer (score 1):

`TextView`s support [SpannableStrings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html). You can either make your custom `String` or format your string in html and then set it with `tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourString));`

Answer (score 1):

kotlin Solution : 
  For me, the issue was I had a text set in XML through data binding. I had to remove that. then this started taking effect

```
val spannableStringBuilder = SpannableStringBuilder(headerText)
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, headerText.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    spannableStringBuilder.append(" ")
    spannableStringBuilder.append(subText)
    textView.text = spannableStringBuilder
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is in the Strings resources.

```
<string name="sample_string"><![CDATA[<b>Title</b>StackOverflow]]></string>
```

Notice, the text between bold tag (`<b> </b>`) will appear in bold. Similarly, you can set other styles. For eg. `<i>` for italics and `<u>` for underline.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Instead, use this :

First, declare textView

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.t1);
```

Then set it's text to the string you want

```
tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.my_text)));
```

Lastly, use set the typeface for your textView

```
tv1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

And, you are done.