# How to display text combined with mathematical formulas in android?

Tags: android, html, math, webview, formula

I'm developing an android app in which we're going to display some mathematics and physics question with multiple-choice answers.
The text of the questions are ready on a Microsoft Office Word .docx format.

**The text of the questions usually contains formulas and equations and we want to save them in a SQLite database and access to it on android app.**

**The real problem is** how to manage the displaying part, since to the best of my knowledge, we should manage such complex text with html tags.
There are actually about **at least 2000 of these questions** and we're after an optimized solutions for the problem.

and I'm a tough guy ! :) just give me some keywords and I'll go get it done.

So, please share your experiences and suggestions.

Comment: So where are you stuck? You can use standard HTML formatting in Android! Also please post a sample line you want to display and where you are finding it problematic.

Comment: Yes I've already been thinking of using a WebView for displaying such text. But I tried to copy and paste the text from Word to html and it didn't work. do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Hey, might be [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235131/set-textview-text-from-html-formatted-string-resource-in-xml) will be of any help?

Comment: I'd have a look at MathML or MathJAX JavaScript libraries.  Beautiful LaTeX formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution, mentioned in the comments, would be to use MathJAX.

An alternative, if you only have about 2000 formulas, would be to set up TeX on your local machine, generate the formulas, and convert into individual png images.

You could also use HTML+Unicode directly if the formulas are simple.

Comment: Hi Charles, could you give me the link to TeX. Actually, I also thoght about displaying formulas as PNG, but then I should manage the preparation for different screen sizes which is rather smooth, if I know the best dimensions to produce for mdpi , hdpi , ....

Comment: @FarhadFaghihi: The most common Windows version is http://miktex.org/ -- for Linux it's usually already installed with most distros.

Comment: thanks about that, and do u have any ideas or guidelines about managing the size of this PNGs for different screens?

Comment: @FarhadFaghihi: Not really. You could just use CSS to display it at a smaller size for some screens, then use it at full size for others.