# Android - string-array values that have HTML

Tags: android

If I have this string array:

```
<string-array name="htmlstrings">
    <item><i>blah<br />blah</i></item>
    <item><b>1st line<br />2nd line</b></item>
</string-array>
```

And I get it and set it as text:

```
String[] htmlstrings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.htmlstrings);
textV.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlstrings[1]));
```

As output I get:

```
1st line2nd line
```

But I want to get

**1st line**

**2nd line**

For regular strings (not string-array) I know I can get and display HTML with `getText()` like:

```
textV.setText(getText(R.string.onehtmlstring));
```

but I don't know what's the `getText()` equivalent for a string-array.

Comment: I used the line break just to illustrate the problem. What I need is HTML formatting, including bold, italic and font color like I can do with string resources (but not string-array members)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try below code:-

```
Spanned sp = Html.fromHtml( getString(R.string.htmlsource));
tv.setText(sp);
```

or

[Set TextView text from html-formatted string resource in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235131/set-textview-text-from-html-formatted-string-resource-in-xml)

Comment: I can't use `getString()` because it's a string-array. I tried using `Spanned sp = Html.fromHtml(htmlstrings[1]); textV.setText(sp);` but there's no difference, it ignores HTML in the string.

Comment: Enclosing the string in <![CDATA[]> works great, thanks

Comment: @TimSim is link is use full to you ?

Comment: Yup, CDATA saves the day

Answer (score 2):

Use `getTextArray()` to make a CharSequence array, and set your TextView using that array.

```
CharSequence[] htmlchars = getResources().getTextArray(R.array.htmlstrings);
textV.setText(htmlchars[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `CDATA` attribute:

```
<string-array name="channel_link">
    <item><![CDATA[https://news.google.com/news/feeds?pz=1&cf=all&ned=in&hl=en&output=rss]]></item>
</string-array>
```