# How can i make a the text bold which is stored in a string variable?

Tags: android, html, string, material-design, android-alertdialog

I want to make the text stored inside a string variable to bold.

String buttonText = t.getText().toString();
                String val = map.get(buttonText);

```
          new MaterialDialog.Builder(LearningMode.this)
                    .iconRes(BalloonColor.get(2))
                    .limitIconToDefaultSize() 
                    .title("Meaning")

                    .content(buttonText+"\n"+val)

                    .positiveText("Continue")
                    .cancelable(false)
                    .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                            mover.resume();
                        }
                    })

                    .show();
```

at .content(buttonText+"\n"+val) 
i want the string stored inside this to become bold.
i have tried html.fromhtml it is not working

like this Html.fromHtml(" < b > "+buttonText+" < / b >")

*added space in the above  as it is converting to bold*

and other methods like declaring in strings.xml with < b > wont work here as i'm dealing it programmatically here!

ultimately when the string button text is displayed in the output sholud be bold.

i have already referred this [Set TextView text from html-formatted string resource in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3235131/2811343)

Update:
There is no textview used.

Someone please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MaterialDialog.Builder` class's `content(CharSequence)` method should work just fine for making text bold, as long as you pass in some `CharSequence` that supports bold text. I know you said `Html.fromHtml()` isn't working, but in my tests it works perfectly. Here's a really simple activity that's a proof of concept:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();

        String myString = "test";

        new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                .title("Hello world")
                .content(Html.fromHtml("this is a <b>" + myString + "</b>"))
                .positiveText("OK")
                .show();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of adding like this .content(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + buttonText + "</b> <br> "+val+"</br>"))


I added like this!!!
 .content(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + buttonText + "</b> <br> ")+val+"</br>")

this small mistake ate hours of my time!!!

thanks to @Ben P , your answer helped me realize this!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 buttonText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Comment: sorry buttonText is a String variable! typeface can be used on a string variable i guess.. i tried it is showing error

Comment: Can you elaborate further on your solution?

Comment: Instead of adding like this .content(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + buttonText + "</b> <br> "+val+"</br>")) I added like this!!! .content(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + buttonText + "</b> <br> ")+val+"</br>")

Answer (score 1):

You may use  SpannableString for it. say you ave a TextView called txt then the code is:

```
 SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("HELLOO");
 StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);

 sb.setSpan(bss, 0, sb.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

 txt.setText(sb);
```

Updated

As I seen in material dialog library it has bug for that so try below code

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        return new MaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .title(R.string.about)
                .positiveText(R.string.dismiss)
                .content(fromHtml(getString(R.string.about_body)))
                .contentLineSpacing(1.6f)
                .build();


    }
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static Spanned fromHtml(String html){
    Spanned result;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        result = Html.fromHtml(html,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
    } else {
        result = Html.fromHtml(html);
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

for more https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/issues/1290

Comment: this one is also not working! i don't know where the mistake is! sharing which code of me will help?!
I'm no using any textview here..

Comment: @ranjithstar256 are you using any third party library for dialog? and want to set content text bold am i right?

Comment: Yes! I'm using this! https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs thanks for asking the right question!